# Align & Rotate a plane automatically to a complex shape, "Grounding" a mesh when moving, (auto-rotate to floor?)

Tags: mesh, scripting, transforms, transform-orientation

I have a complex, irregular mesh (a shoe) that I need grounded on it's side, on a plane.  If I use DropIt or other add-ons to ground it, it only hits at the lowest point and the mesh seems to float at other points.
[image]
I want the plane (or the complex mesh) to rotate slightly, automatically.  I do not need an animation, although if that let me ground it in one or two frames I would be happy with that.
[image]
I have the ability to use python if that helps, but I'm fairly basic to Blender so any clear help would be very appreciated.
I've tried Rigid bodies but the shoe bounces all over the place.  It's almost like I need a bounding box Tight to the shoe, that the plane can snap to on multiple vertices- but it needs to be able to rotate on it's own and I don't want to select any points manually.
Adobe stager does what I want- acts as the floor is the ground, mesh reacts when moving it to "lay" properly.  For a bunch of reasons I don't want to use Stager, but I can't figure this out in Blender! I need to do this across a variety of meshes so not doing anything manual is key here.
Thank you

Comment: Rigid Body should work fine for this. A few things to take into account:

1) Do this for both abjects: select the object > right click > Set Origin > Origin to Geometry.
 2) Same as before: Select and Crt+A (Rotation and Scale)
3) In Scene propierties > Rigid Body, you can increase the substeps and iterations for more accuracy
4) In Rigid Body > Sensitivity, you can set the margin to a low value, like 0.001 or less (it will help)
5) In RG > collisions use convex hulk or mesh